# Continuous query fail in login script

Tags: php, authentication

I'm making a login script but it keeps failing and printing out the "connection failed". Why does the query fail and how can i make this better?

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname") or die('Connection failed.');
mysqli_select_db($connection, 'dbname') or die ("Connection failed.");

$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email=`$email` AND user_pass=`$pass`") or die ('Connection failed.');

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($check_user == 1){
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($check_user);
$_SESSION[‘user_email’]=$email;
header('Location: yay.php');
}else{
echo"<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect.')</script>";
}
}
```

The line that fails:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email=`$email` AND user_pass=`$pass`") or die ('Connection failed.');
```

Comment: `mysqli_select_db($connection, 'dbname') or die ("Connection failed.");` this line useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your query failed.

Why? Because, you're using the wrong type of quotes for your variables, being ticks.

```
$sel_user = "select * from users where user_email = `$email` AND user_pass=`$pass`";
```

Those should be single quotes.

```
$sel_user = "select * from users where user_email = '$email' AND user_pass='$pass'";
```

Checking for errors with http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  would have told you of the syntax error.

This doesn't help you:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users 
                                    WHERE user_email=`$email` 
                                    AND user_pass=`$pass`") 
                                    or die ('Connection failed.');
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

this does:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users 
                                    WHERE user_email=`$email` 
                                    AND user_pass=`$pass`")
                                    or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Plus, you're using curly quotes for `[‘user_email’]` which will also cause your code to fail after you've changed the quotes. (Consult my footnotes on error reporting).

```
$_SESSION['user_email']=$email;
```

and adding `exit;` after header. Your code may want to continue executing.

For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

In regards to your other question, now deleted:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/30695536/ (viewable by OP and 10K+ members)

you had:

```
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db-name");
if (mysqli_connect_error()){
echo"Connection failed.";
}
```

so why are you using this now?

```
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname") or die('Connection failed.');
mysqli_select_db($connection, 'dbname') or die ("Connection failed.");
```

- `mysqli_select_db($connection, 'dbname')` you've already selected your database.

where the error you stated being (in your other question):

> But i'm getting the error above in the title (mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given).

Plus this line:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($check_user);
```

You're using the wrong variable for it `$check_user`, that should be `$query`.

- Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

As an example from the manual:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

        /* fetch associative array */
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
        }
```

---

**Footnotes:**

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: No worries. Sorry to bother you, but it just seemed strange. We might as well delete the irrelevant comments though. :)

Comment: @Anonymous No worries, and I appreciate the comments though. Will delete other comments then, *cheers*